# How can I run FEST Swing tests in Jenkins?

Tags: java, swing, testing, jenkins, fest

I'm trying to run FEST Swing tests on Jenkins as a service on Windows 7.

I have already allowed the service to interect with the desktop with the necessary permission to do so. It was no use, though.

Most of what I found on the internet either shows how to do it on Linux (through the CLI shell) or how to run it on the prompt, which is not what I'm looking for.

I have also found some vague discussions on how to run the tests letting the desktop available (which was by running it on a VM). But that's not what I need either.

I need to run the GUI tests just as they are run on Eclipse, with the graphical appearance on the desktop. When I try to do it, the following happens:

`execguitest:

    [echo] ----------------------------------------------

    [echo] project-name: Executing project's GUI tests

    [echo] ----------------------------------------------

    [junit] Running dev.AllGUITests

    [junit] null

    [junit] null

    [junit] null

    [junit] Tests run:33, Failures: 3, Errors: 30, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 112,375 sec

    [junit Test dev.AllGUITests FAILED`

Does anyone have a clue on how can it be done?

P.S.: Sorry for any english mistakes. English is not my mother language.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Djaildo.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320409/how-to-make-gui-test-without-displaying-in-fest-swing

Answer (score 2):

The [Documentation of FEST](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Continuous+Integration) shows you how to configure Hudson (almost the same as Jenkins) unter Windows and how to run the tests on virtual Xvfb devices (Linux) for execution without real display devices.

Answer (score 2):

I did it with the [Jenkins-XVNC-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin).

Look at [this](http://blog.dahanne.net/2011/07/18/run-ui-tests-on-a-headless-jenkins-hudson-continuous-integration-server-running-ubuntu/).