# Failing to run FEST Swing tests on Jenkins

Tags: swing, unit-testing, user-interface, jenkins, fest

I'm trying to run FEST Swing tests on Jenkins as a service on Windows 7.

I have already allowed the service to interect with the desktop with the necessary permission to do so. It was no use, though.

Most of what I found on the internet either shows how to do it on Linux (through the CLI shell) or how to run it on the prompt, which is not what I'm looking for.

I have also found some vague discussions on how to run the tests letting the desktop available (which was by running it on a VM). But that's not what I need either.

I need to run the GUI tests just as they are run on Eclipse, with the graphical appearance on the desktop. When I try to do it, the following happens:

`execguitest:

     [echo] ----------------------------------------------

     [echo] project-name: Executing project's GUI tests

     [echo] ----------------------------------------------

     [junit] Running dev.AllGUITests

     [junit] null

     [junit] null

     [junit] null

     [junit] Tests run:33, Failures: 3, Errors: 30, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 112,375 sec

     [junit Test dev.AllGUITests FAILED`

Does anyone have a clue on how can it be done?

P.S.: Sorry for any english mistakes. English is not my mother language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run FEST Swing tests in Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035110/how-can-i-run-fest-swing-tests-in-jenkins). Please edit your Question there if something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

A service does not interact with the desktop by default. You need to allow the Jenkins service (if run Jenkins outside of any other app server) to interact with the desktop. However, I am not sure if that is sufficient to run UI tests. Investigate more in how to run headless (unattended) ui tests on Windows.